# For loop not iterating through columns r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to write a loop that will iterate through columns `64:111` in a data frame, and set `[64,1] = 0`, then `[65,1:2] = 0`, then `[66,1:3] = 0` etc (Months_out starts at `0` and increments by `1`).  I can't tell why my loop is only running once, what am I doing wrong?

```
for (i in 64:111) {
   Prod1[cbind(1:Prod1$Months_Out+1,i)] <- 0
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output. It would probably be safe to scale down the problem to a more manageable size for the question.

Comment: If you are looping through columns 64 through 111, then what does `[64,1] = 0` mean? This typically means the element in row 64 and column 1. If that is incorrect, please alter your notation to conform with the standards `[r, c]` that are common in mathematics, statistics, and most if not all programming languages, including R.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses, and apologies, I confused the order of rows and columns. Your solution did it for me Alex P, thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jess did you know you can close this question by accepting Alex P's answer? (Check mark to the left of his answer)

Comment: I did not know that, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, the data.frame subset goes like `df[row,column]`
It seems like you might have that backwards.
Second, I'm not sure why you are using `cbind()` within the brackets of a dataframe subset.

Here's how I might do it:

```
rows <- 1
for (i in 64:111) {
    Prod1[1:rows, i] <- 0
    rows = rows+1
}
```

Does that work for you?